# Is it possible to pass Rcpp functions to a child process?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have defined a function using Rcpp and it runs in the current session. So I tried to use `future` package to compile the same function in each worker process, but I run into the error

> Error: Error 1 occurred building shared library.

Is there an easy to way to share Rcpp functions without having to build a package?

See MWE below

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
            NumericVector test(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
            return x;
            }')

# test if compiled successful
test(1:2)

lapply(list(1:2), test) # works

future_lapply(list(1:2), function(a) {
  library(Rcpp)
  cppFunction('
     NumericVector test(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
     return x;
  }')
  test(a)
 })
```

Comment: What you want to do is fundamentally equivalent to spreading Rcpp-based functions via, say, `foreach`. In short, you can't. They sit at a "random" local memory point.  The only _reliable_ way is to stick them in a package and have each worker load the package. That will work.

Comment: Is there a way to share the location via a pointer and just pass the pointer to the worker?

Comment: The problem is the memory content that needs transferring. Which you can't. Hence a package.

Comment: I will accept the answer "No", then.

Comment: I think the answer isn't "No", but "Make a package".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is really equivalent to spreading Rcpp-based functions via, say, `foreach`. In short, you cannot serialize a Rcpp-based function and pass it along.

They sit at a "random" local memory point. The only reliable way is to stick them in a package and have each worker load the package. That will work.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to build a package (e.g., utils) inside an R package? Or should I create another package just for the Rcpp-based function?

Comment: There is no real cost or overhead to packages. One-function packages do exists.  Start with `Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackagenamehere")`, add your function, and you are essentially done.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am planning on submitting the main package to CRAN. Based on your recommendation, I need to submit the sub-package to CRAN, too. Is that correct?

Comment: You are writing a package.  Stick the C++ function you are concerned with into that package.  Why would you need another?  Also, we have a mailing list for Rcpp -- likely a better place that comments of an unrelated 3 1/2 year old question.

Comment: Thanks. I joined the mailing list. But my problem is this very topic. I do not think it is unrelated. The C++ function that I added to my R package, and compiled using Rcpp, is available throughout the package. However, it is not available for parLapply workers.